# Laravel Deployment in CPanel return HTTP Error 500

Tags: php, laravel

I think this might be one cliche question but this really confusing me.

I have Laravel App (Ver 5.6) to be deployed in my CPanel. I have followed all the steps which mentioned in this tutorial,

https://medium.com/laravel-power-devs/deploy-laravel-projects-on-shared-hosting-2008be6f6f03

And then, when i try to running it, it showing me error as below,

[image]

First thing came up in my mind is PHP version issue. Yes, i found out that my PHP version is outdated which is v5.6. and i changed it.

[image: CPanel PHP Setting]

But, when im refresh the site, the error still appear. and someone tell me this might be caused by code error and i check the error_log file, so here it is,

```
[12-Dec-2018 15:31:11 Asia/Country] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home/root/laravelapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 500
```

So, this part is really make me stressful because most of Laravel communities tell me this error happen because of PHP version in my CPanel. Like i said earlier, the version already changed to v7.1.

Did you guys have facing same situation like me? Please help me out. am really don't know what to do right now. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure your PHP version is changed? Have you checked running $php -v or phpinfo() ?

Comment: @TejashwiKalpTaru i did checked it through ssh with command php -v inside the site root folder. and here is the result, https://imgur.com/a/ExRmn4d. Can you justify?

Comment: As you can see from the screenshot, your PHP version is still 5.6.39. If you have changed the PHP version from Cpanel, you might need to restart the server. Or you can contact your service provider to change the PHP version for you

Comment: @TejashwiKalpTaru do i need to restart the apache or whole server? if restart the apache, then i already did it a couple of times. :'(

Comment: Hmm, then try a server restart. My guess, it won't work. Ask your hosting provider to set that for you

Comment: @TejashwiKalpTaru alright. Good idea. Thank you for your feedback btw.

Comment: check you php version, what is hosting php version and what is your laravel php version?

Comment: @JasimJuwel my laravel version is 5.6. hosting php version i've changed it to v7.1. But when i check through ssh with php -v command, it showing the php version still 5.6, https://imgur.com/BZXCWrH

Answer (score 0):

Changing the php version is not enough. You actually need to change the `php-fpm` executable too.

```
[Client] --calls--> [Web server] --forwards to--> [PHP FPM] --asks--> [PHP]
```

So if your `fpm` instance is pointing at the old php version you'll still get your error. To check everything is setup correctly:

```
sudo php-fpm -i | grep "PHP Version"
>> should show you which version is being used
```

If the binary is not in the path you'll have to locate it:

```
sudo find / -type f -name php-fpm
```

Alternatively look for it in `/usr/bin/php-fpm`, `/usr/sbin/php-fpm`, `/usr/local/bin/php-fpm`, `/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm`. If you find more than one binary, try to call it with the `-i` option.

```
sudo /usr/local/sbin/php-fpm -i | grep "PHP Version"
```

Then in your webserver config you'll have to make sure you're using the correct fpm connection. Usually it's a socket, but could also be a fastCGI forward

```
sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/your-site
```

Look for this line and make sure you're using the correct version.

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
```

(If you use apache it's similar, but you'll have to search for the correct steps there.)

If you're not using the correct version of fpm you'll have to start the process by executing the `php-fpm` binary for `php7.1` and point the webserver to the correct socket.

Comment: do i need to restart the php-fpm service first?

Comment: You can check the version without restarting. If it's pointing at php 5.6 you can just locate the `php-fpm` binary for php 7.1 and start it. No need to stop the old one, although you should to avoid confusion.

Comment: so i did checked it like u said but im using this "ps aux | grep php-fpm" command. and here is the result. do you have any clue? ps: sorry, im still new in ssh.

Comment: You can just write this in the console: `php-fpm -i | grep "PHP Version"` when you use `ps aux` you'll only see that the php-fpm process is running.

Comment: That means that the php-fpm binary is not in your "searchable" path. you can use `find / -name php-fpm -type f` to look for the binary. Or just check if it's in any of these directories: `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/sbin`, `/usr/local/sbin`

Comment: alright. so now i have a few path shown as result. right now what i need to do with the path?

Comment: You can now use the full path to execute the binary. I have edited my answer to account for that, e.g. `/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm -i | grep "PHP Version"` When you find the right one execute it with no arguments, e.g. `/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm`

Comment: All paths i ran return me error and permission denied. Still don't know what is the problem. :'(

Comment: prefix the execution with sudo, e.g. `sudo /usr/bin/php-fpm -i | grep "PHP Version"`

Comment: Still not working. I will try contacting my hosting provider and report my case.

Comment: I dont know what is the problem. Before this i have successfully deployed my laravel project in CPanel too with other hosting provider. But with this provider, cannot deploy my laravel project even one project.

Comment: Yes sometimes it's just too complex to fix, especially on a hosted system. I hope you resolve this issue :)

Comment: Yes exactly. Once i resolve this, i will update my answer here. :)